# What makes this class non-Serializable?

Tags: java, serialization, notserializableexception

Im serializing Student class that contains an instance of Statistics class, both classes implement Serializable but the stack trace says this one is not serializable. if you have any more questions let me know.

filename.txt:

```
Stud Qu1 Qu2 Qu3 Qu4 Qu5
1234 052 007 100 078 034
2134 090 036 090 077 030
3124 100 045 020 090 070
4532 011 017 081 032 077
5678 020 012 045 078 034
6134 034 080 055 078 045
7874 060 100 056 078 078
8026 070 010 066 078 056
9893 034 009 077 078 020
1947 045 040 088 078 055
2877 055 050 099 078 080
3189 022 070 100 078 077
4602 089 050 091 078 060
5405 011 011 000 078 010
6999 000 098 089 078 020
```

Driver:

```
package Driver;
import Model.Statistics;
import Model.Student;
import utilities.Util;
import utilities.Serialization;

public class Driver {
    public static final boolean DEBUG_MODE = true;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student lab2[] = new Student[40];
        // Populate the student array by reading from file
        lab2 = Util.readFile("E:\\CIS35A\\Assignment 6\\src\\filename.txt", lab2);
        Statistics statlab2 = new Statistics();

        // Calculate the quiz stats
        statlab2.findLow(lab2);
        statlab2.findHigh(lab2);
        statlab2.findAvg(lab2);

        // create a file for each student via serialization
        for(int i = 0; i < lab2.length; i++){
            lab2[i].setClassStats(statlab2); // <---- if i comment this out it runs, but why? also I need it to store that data before serialization.
            Serialization.serialize( new String("Student")+
                    ((Integer)i).toString()+
                    new String(".stu"), lab2[i]);
        }

        if(DEBUG_MODE){

        }
    }

}
```

Util Class:

```
package utilities;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import Model.Student;

public class Util {
    public static Student[] readFile(String filename, Student[] stu) {
        // Reads the file and builds student array.

        int studentCounter = -99;//init to a value I know is out of bounds
        try {
            // Open the file using FileReader Object.
            FileReader file = new FileReader(filename);

            // load the file into a buffer
            BufferedReader fileBuff = new BufferedReader(file);

            // In a loop read a line using readLine method.
            boolean eof = false;
            studentCounter = -1;//set to -1 because the first line is the table headings
            while (!eof) {
                String line = fileBuff.readLine();
                if (line == null){
                    eof = true;
                    continue;
                }
                else if(studentCounter >= 0){
                    // Tokenize each line using StringTokenizer Object
                    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line);

                    // Create the Student
                    stu[studentCounter] = new Student();

                    int quizCounter = -1;// init to -1 because the first token
                                         // is not going to be a quiz score
                    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                        String currentToken = st.nextToken();

                        // Each token is converted from String to Integer using parseInt method
                        int value = Integer.parseInt(currentToken);

                        // Value is then saved in the right property of Student Object.
                        if(quizCounter == -1){
                            // Store the student ID in the student instance we created
                            stu[studentCounter].setSID(value);
                        }
                        else{
                            // Store the quiz grades in the students score list
                            stu[studentCounter].setScore(value, quizCounter);
                        }
                        quizCounter++;
                    }
                }
                studentCounter++;
            }
            fileBuff.close();




        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return trimArray(stu, studentCounter);
    }

    /*
     * this method is used for shortening the 
     * array to the number of elements used
     * */
    private static Student[] trimArray(Student[] arr, int count){
        Student[] newArr = new Student[count];
        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
            newArr[i] = arr[i];
        }
        return newArr;
    }
}
```

Serialization Class:

```
package utilities;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

public class Serialization {
    /*
     * This method will serialize any object and store it in a file with the 
     * filename provided and return true if successful
     * */
    public static boolean serialize(String filename, Object obj){
        try {
            ObjectOutputStream serializer = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filename));
            serializer.writeObject(obj);
            serializer.close();
            if(true){
                System.out.println("sucesss!!!!!!!!!");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    /*
     * This method will take any serialized object from a file with the 
     * filename provided and return the object or null
     * */
    public static Object deSerialize(String filename){
        try {
            ObjectInputStream deSerializer = new ObjectInputStream(
                                                new FileInputStream(filename));
            Object data = deSerializer.readObject();
            deSerializer.close();
            return data;
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

Student Class:

```
package Model;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Student implements Serializable{
    private int SID;
    private int scores[] = new int[5];
    private Statistics classStats;

    // Setters and Getters
    public int getSID() {
        return SID;
    }

    public void setSID(int sID) {
        SID = sID;
    }

    public int[] getScores() {
        return scores;
    }
    public int getScore(int index) {
        return scores[index];
    }

    public void setScores(int[] scores) {
        this.scores = scores;
    }
    public void setScore(int score, int index) {
        this.scores[index] = score;
    }

    public Statistics getClassStats() {
        return classStats;
    }

    public void setClassStats(Statistics classStats) {
        this.classStats = classStats;
    }

    // Methods for printing quiz scores and student ID
    public void printScores(){
        System.out.printf("------- Quiz Scores ------- %n");
        for(int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++){
            System.out.printf("Quiz %d: %d %n", i+1, scores[i]);
        }
        System.out.printf("----- End Quiz Scores ----- %n");
    }

    public void printStudentID(){
        System.out.printf("Student ID: %d %n", SID);
    }


}
```

Statistics Class:

```
package Model;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Statistics implements Serializable{
    private int[] lowScores = new int[5];
    private int[] highScores = new int[5];
    private float[] avgScores = new float[5];

    public void findLow(Student[] studs) {
        /*
         * This method will find the lowest score and store it in an array named
         * lowscores.
         */
        for(int i = 0; i< lowScores.length; i++){
            int current = 919;
            for(int j = 0; j< studs.length; j++){
                if(studs[j].getScore(i) < current){
                    current = studs[j].getScore(i);
                }
            }
            lowScores[i] = current;
        }
    }

    public void findHigh(Student[] studs) {
        /*
         * This method will find the highest score and store it in an array
         * named highscores.
         */

        for(int i = 0; i< highScores.length; i++){
            int current = -99;
            for(int j = 0; j< studs.length; j++){
                if(studs[j].getScore(i) > current){
                    current = studs[j].getScore(i);
                }
            }
            highScores[i] = current;
        }
    }

    public void findAvg(Student[] studs) {
        /*
         * This method will find avg score for each quiz and store it in an
         * array named avgscores.
         */

        for(int i = 0; i< avgScores.length; i++){
            float total = 0;
            for(int j = 0; j< studs.length; j++){
                total += studs[j].getScore(i);
            }
            avgScores[i] = total/studs.length;
        }
    }

    // Methods for printing the highs, lows, and average scores for each quiz
    public void printHighScores(){
        System.out.printf("------- High Scores ------- %n");
        for(int i = 0; i < highScores.length; i++){
            System.out.printf("Quiz %d: %d %n", i+1, highScores[i]);
        }
        System.out.printf("----- End High Scores ----- %n");
    }

    public void printLowScores(){
        System.out.printf("------- Low Scores ------- %n");
        for(int i = 0; i < lowScores.length; i++){
            System.out.printf("Quiz %d: %d %n", i+1, lowScores[i]);
        }
        System.out.printf("----- End Low Scores ----- %n");
    }

    public void printAvgScores(){
        System.out.printf("------- Average Scores ------- %n");
        for(int i = 0; i < avgScores.length; i++){
            System.out.printf("Quiz %d: %f %n", i+1, avgScores[i]);
        }
        System.out.printf("----- End Average Scores ----- %n");
    }
}
```

Stack Trace:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: Model.Statistics
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at utilities.Serialization.serialize(Serialization.java:18)
    at Driver.Driver.main(Driver.java:24)
```

Comment: You don't provide enough info to reproduce the problem...

Comment: No. You need to show the stack trace. The actual class that isn't Serializable is named in the exception.

Comment: I copied your code and pasted in into a new project on my computer. It worked (it produced files Student0.stu to Student14.stu and printed "sucesss!!!!!!!!!" 15 times)

Comment: color me confused, on   my local code i was changing stuff to see if i could get the bottom of the issue and removed serializable from the class to see if it would yeild the exact same stack trace, i must have forgot to put it back. but i definitely tested this code before i posted and it failed, since then i recompiled the bin and updated to the latest jdk and jre. sorry for the trouble

Answer (score 1):

The Statistics class as you have shown it *should* be serializable.  It implements `Serializable` and its 3 fields are natively serializable.  That should be sufficient.

I suspect that the problem is that the class you are actually trying to serialize is different:

- You may be showing us the wrong version of the source code
- The class might need recompiling
- A JAR file might need rebuilding
- The JAR file might need redeploying

Comment: thats what i thought, but i just found something else interesting. when I comment out this line in Driver, it executes without exceptions : "lab2[i].setClassStats(statlab2);" . then i tried creating an instance of Statistics in the Student class(Statistics classStats = new Statistics;) instead of just "Statistics classStats;" and that triggers the exception even with the line in the driver commented out.

Comment: im trying to serialize the student class which contains an instance of Statistics class which is causing trouble, no idea why. I assure you that this is the sourcecode that produces my issue.

Answer (score -1):

I reinstalled the latest jdk, recompiled the code and reboot a couple times and now the code posted above works

Comment: The only part of this that was necessary was the recompilation.